# Hash outputs in Taproot transactions

Tags: taproot, output

I'm using the test vector from Bip341 to generate the Hash outputs in the test transaction. My procedure is as follows:

- Serialise amount as 8-byte little endian
- Serialise scriptpubkey including length
- Concatenate all outputs using format: Amount + scriptpubkey
- Sha256 of concatenated array

However I can't get the desired hash of `a2e6dab7c1f0dcd297c8d61647fd17d821541ea69c3cc37dcbad7f90d4eb4bc5`

Can anyone see a mistake in the procedure?
Thanks.